# C# LINQ Query to Sum Data Groupby Column?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Data View that contains a `DATE` Column and a `POWER` Column. I am filling this data view from an XML file which I get from a particular link and I want to sum the `POWER` Column Group by "DATE". I use this linq query to get it:

```
var query = from row in _Hdt.AsEnumerable()
        group row by row.Field<int>("DATE") into grp
        orderby grp.Key
        select new
        {
        DATE = grp.Key,
        Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("KW"))
        };

        foreach (var grp in query)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grp.Id, grp.Sum);
        }
        }
```

but i am getting errors:

```
Error   1   Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    
Error   2   Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   3   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct     
Error   4   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct     
Error   5   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct     
Error   6   Identifier expected C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.MUSEWERX-
Error   7   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct     
Error   8   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct     
Error   9   A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods 
Error   10  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

I hope for your replies.

Comment: You need to put this query inside a method, which in turn must be inside a class. Either that or you are missing / have to many brackets somewhere.

Comment: -1 for not bothering to put dots between sentences. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not LINQ query itself but incorrect placing of braces.

Apparently, the compiler decided that your `return` statement is right inside of the class declaration. Of course you can't `return` from a class, you can only `return` from a method.

I can't tell the problem right away because you only posted a piece of your code, however I noticed there are two closing `}` instead of just one matching `foreach`—could that be the reason compiler thought method is over?

Comment: now i am getting error, (Specified cast is not valid.) and hilighting this after error (row.Field<DateTime>("DATE"))                     var query = from row in _Hdt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<DateTime>("DATE") into grp
            orderby grp.Key
            select new
            {
            DATE = grp.Key,
            Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("KW"))
            };

            foreach (var grp in query)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grp.DATE, grp.Sum);
            }

Comment: @Syed: please create a new question, this is clearly a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which returns an `IEnumerable` and place your code into it.Do not directly write the code inside the class.

EDIT:

```
public IEnumerable MethodAmk(){
          var query = from row in _Hdt.AsEnumerable()         
                      group row by row.Field<int>("DATE") into grp         
                      orderby grp.Key         
                      select new {         
                            DATE = grp.Key,         
                            Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("KW"))         
            };          
          foreach (var grp in query)         
                {         
                 Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grp.Id, grp.Sum);         
               } 
          return query;
}
```

Comment: in my code how would i return IEnumerable after placing it in the code ??

Comment: @Syed Raza I edited my answer with a code snippet with your code in a method which returns an `IEnumerable` that is your `query`.